# Sticking a missle to spaceship,pygame

Tags: pygame

So I want a missle to stick to my spaceship,so if the spaceship moves the missle will move with it.
Should I make a global variable and pass players position into the missle x & y parameters? cause they are in two different classes

```
Missle1    = Missle(screen,(x_pos,y_pos),playerShip)
```

---

```
class PlayerShip(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, screen, (x, y)):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.screen = screen
        self.image = pygame.image.load("player.png")
        self.image = self.image.convert()
        tranColor = self.image.get_at((1, 1))
        self.image.set_colorkey(tranColor)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (x, y)
        self.health = 100


    def update(self):
        x_pos =self.rect.centerx 
        y_pos =self.rect.centery
```

Comment: Why don't you put a missile instance in the player class ?
Then you could change it's position direcly in the player update function. Then draw it in the player draw function (i guess that's what you want to do)

Comment: because it has its own class

Comment: But as far a i know, you can do something like this :
PlayerClass():
  def __init__(self,..):
    self.ship = Ship();

Then every ship will have it's one missile

Comment: could you give me an example.This is the name of my class.

    `class Missle(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
        def __init__(self,screen, (x, y), playerShip):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better if you'd share the whole code... Your Missile() class is pretty obscure to me but I can't have a look at it like this.

I deem classes to be the best solution here, but I surely wouldn't mind to be corrected in this :)

I suggest to create two classes: a general Ship() class and a Missile() class (note: It's spelled "missile" with an "i" before the "l"!).

It could look somewhat like this:

```
class Ship(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, ...):
         #your code here
         self.missiles = [Missiles(x, y, x_offset, y_offset)]

    def update(self):
        #update ship's x and y coordinates
        for missile in self.missiles:
            missile.update(self.rect.center)
        #Did you notice? We call "update" for each of the instances of Missile() in our
        #ship's "self.missiles" list and pass it our self.rect.center as argument

class Missile(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, x_offset, y_offset):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.x_offset = x_offset #how much offset to the ship's x?
        self.y_offset = y_offset

    def update(self, (x, y)):
        self.x = x + self.x_offset
        self.y = y + self.y_offset
```

of course there's some math to do. E.g. when the ship changes its angle, then the missiles also should and then the x/y_offsets don't fit anymore. But I think, people learn most from trying and thinking on their own, so I don't go into detail with this now ;) Try and ask if you can't get it running.

Comment: Exactly what i meant to say, but had no time to write it down yesterday.
This is in fact not really related to python. It would work the same in any other OO language.

Comment: Of course, you're right about this :)
I also forgot to add to my answer: this way, with a general Ship() class, one can instantiate several ships, enemies and friends, if one ever wants to expand the game later.